# My Access Vba is giving an automation error '-2147023170 (800706be)' when automating word

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a database to extract data that I need to present.  Because I need to present the data in both landscape and portrait an access report will not do the trick.  I am therefore using Access vba to put the data into a word template.  However when I run the code over the full data I keep encountering an automation error.  The word application ceases to exist.

I have queried and I don't think I have any of the common code errors associated with this problem, so no unreferenced word objects etc.  I have also replaced all references to word constants like wdcell with their integer values.  I have run through the code in debug, and when I run through in debug, the code never fails.  I have put in some pauses (a function that waits a specific time and performs DoEvents) to see if that helps

```
Function MoveMergePaste(wdInputName As String, oWord As Word.Application, oWdocMerged As Word.Document) As Long
Dim oWdocMove As Word.Document
Dim oWdocMoveMerged As Word.Document
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

On Error GoTo ERR_MoveMergePaste

Pause 1
strSQL = "SELECT T.* FROM tblMovementTemp AS T INNER JOIN tblMovementHeader AS H "
strSQL = strSQL & "ON T.FundId = H.FundId ORDER BY tblPosition"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

Pause 0.5
Set oWdocMove = oWord.Documents.Open(wdInputName)
Pause 0.5
oWdocMove.Bookmarks("PremiumDataStart").Select

rst.MoveFirst
oWord.Selection.TypeText rst!tblElement
oWord.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=12 '(wdcell)
oWord.Selection.TypeText rst!TotalUnits
rst.MoveNext
While Not rst.EOF
    oWord.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=12 '(wdcell)
    oWord.Selection.TypeText rst!tblElement
    oWord.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=12 '(wdcell)
    oWord.Selection.TypeText rst!TotalUnits
    rst.MoveNext
Wend

'Start mail merge Claims
'------------------------------------------------
With oWdocMove.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = 0 'wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource _
    Name:=CurrentProject.FullName, _
    AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    LinkToSource:=True, _
    Connection:="QUERY mailmerge", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [tblMovementHeader] "
    .Destination = 0 'wdSendToNewDocument
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

'Copy movement data into merged document
'------------------------------------------------
Set oWdocMoveMerged = oWord.ActiveDocument
oWdocMoveMerged.Select
oWord.Selection.WholeStory
oWord.Selection.Copy
oWdocMerged.Select
oWord.Selection.EndKey Unit:=6 '(wdstory)
oWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

MoveMergePaste = 0

EXIT_MoveMergePaste:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Close files
    '------------------------------------------------
    oWdocMove.Close SaveChanges:=False
    oWdocMoveMerged.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Release objects
    '------------------------------------------------
    Set oWdocMove = Nothing
    Set oWdocMoveMerged = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Exit Function

ERR_MoveMergePaste:
    MoveMergePaste = Err.Number
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume EXIT_MoveMergePaste

End Function
```

I pass a string which is for the path of a word template, a word application object, and an existing open word document.  the routine builds a record set of data, opens the word template, finds a bookmark in the template and then writes data from the recordset to the template.  Once it has done this it performs a mail merge on the template and copies the data from the newly created merged document into the open document.  It returns 0 if successful.  It closes the template and merged document and releases the objects.

Mostly it works, but far too often to make it usable I get the automation error. '-2147023170 (800706be)'. The error usually occurs because the word has ceased to exist.  If I break the code the line of code that returns the error is

oWdocMove.Bookmarks("PremiumDataStart").Select

But the line is OK, the error is because word no longer exists.

Comment: Assuming this is because the Word Application instance has been closed by the user (or maybe another part of the program) what about creating your own instance of `Word.Application`, and opening the document via that instance. That way, you could hold onto it until you know that everything is finished. Otherwise, I don't think you have any sort of guarantee of the Application instance's availability.

Comment: I am running it myself, not touching the keyboard while it is running,  So no, the application is not being closed by the user.  The program that calls this routine does creates its own instance of word already.  There is nothing in the code to close the instance of word until the end of the program.

Comment: So what does this -- _the error is because word no longer exists_ -- mean? Also, can you read properties on `oWdocMove`?

Comment: The word application has quit (crashed?) in the middle of the process.  It quits without any error message or interruption to code.  Once the word application has quit, the access code can no longer manipulate any of the word objects in that application.  When the word application quits any open word objects are closed as they only exist in the word application.  At this point I cannot get any properties for the document oWdocMove since it is no longer available to the program.  The program "notices" that word has quit when it tries to do something with a word object and cannot.